# Optimise python function fetching multi-level json attributes

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, flask, flask-restful

I have a 3 level json file. I am fetching the values of some of the attributes from each of the 3 levels of json. At the moment, the execution time of my code is pathetic as it is taking about 2-3 minutes to get the results on my web page. I will be having a much larger json file to deal with in production.

I am new to python and flask and haven't done much of web programming. Please suggest me ways I could optimise my below code! Thanks for help, much appreciated.

```
import json
import urllib2
import flask
from flask import request
def Backend():
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/surveillance/api/v1/cameras/'
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    response = json.loads(response)
    components = list(response['children'])
    urlComponentChild = []
    for component in components:
        urlComponent = str(url + component + '/')
        responseChild = urllib2.urlopen(urlComponent).read()
        responseChild = json.loads(responseChild)
        camID = str(responseChild['id'])
        camName = str(responseChild['name'])
        compChildren = responseChild['children']
        compChildrenName = list(compChildren)
        for compChild in compChildrenName:
                href = str(compChildren[compChild]['href'])
                ID = str(compChildren[compChild]['id'])
                urlComponentChild.append([href,ID])
    myList = []
    for each in urlComponentChild:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(each[0]).read()
        response = json.loads(response)
        url = each[0] + '/recorder'
        responseRecorder = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        responseRecorder = json.loads(responseRecorder)
        username = str(response['subItems']['surveillance:config']['properties']['username'])
        password = str(response['subItems']['surveillance:config']['properties']['password'])
        manufacturer = str(response['properties']['Manufacturer'])
        model = str(response['properties']['Model'])
        status = responseRecorder['recording']
        myList.append([each[1],username,password,manufacturer,model,status])
    return myList
APP = flask.Flask(__name__)
@APP.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    """ Displays the index page accessible at '/'
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return flask.render_template('index.html', response = Backend())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.debug=True
    APP.run(port=62000)
```

Comment: I'd suggest either threading or caching - all these http requests you're making are almost certainly the holdup as you have to wait for each one to complete. The threading solution would be to make all http requests on separate threads. The caching solution would be to instead of requesting from surveillance every time you get a request, routinely request from surveillance regardless, then just return the most recent data when you get a new request to your server rather than re-requesting new data (I can expand in an answer if you think either would be helpful)

Comment: Caching solution suits more for this sort of problem. Can you explain more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, caching. So what we're going to do is start returning values to the user instantly based on data we already have, rather than generating new data every time. This means that the user might get slightly less up to date data than is theoretically possible to get, but it means that the data they do receive they receive as quickly as is possible given the system you're using.

So we'll keep your backend function as it is. Like I said, you could certainly speed it up with multithreading (If you're still interested in that, the 10 second version is that I would use [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) to asynchronously get data from a list of urls).

But, rather than call it in response to the user every time a user requests data, we'll just call it routinely every once in a while. This is almost certainly something you'd want to do eventually anyway, because it means you don't have to generate brand new data for each user, which is extremely wasteful. We'll just keep some data on hand in a variable, update that variable as often as we can, and return whatever's in that variable every time we get a new request.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

data = None

def Backend():
    .....

def main_loop():
    while True:
        sleep(LOOP_DELAY_TIME_SECONDS)
        global data
        data = Backend()

APP = flask.Flask(__name__)
@APP.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    """ Displays the index page accessible at '/'
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Return whatever data we currently have cached
        return flask.render_template('index.html', response = data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = Backend() # Need to make sure we grab data before we start the server so we never return None to the user
    Thread(target=main_loop).start() #Loop and grab new data at every loop
    APP.debug=True
    APP.run(port=62000)
```

DISCLAIMER: I've used Flask and threading before for a few projects, but I am by no means an expert on it or web development, at all. Test this code before using it for anything important (or better yet, find someone who knows that they're doing before using it for anything important)

Edit: data will have to be a global, sorry about that - hence the disclaimer

---

Comment: Thanks for your help James! Can you explain me more how this code is working at an algorithmic level? I ran the modified version and performance has degraded a bit. I am considering your other solution as well which is to use grerequests. Adding that to code will do wonders!

Comment: Hmmm... Unless I made some sort of mistake here (which is entirely possible), if it's true that the speed hasn't gotten better (and possibly got worse), then I doubt your problem will be solved by grequests either, as the bottleneck is likely elsewhere. Did you notice that the return line is now "response=data" rather than "reponse=Backend()"? That's critical.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that James. I am noticing that http requests are running in the back-end all the time. So, based on the logic that you provided, the results will be returned on the front-end without auto-refreshing the page, isn't it? So to test if this is working, I will need to change the values coming from the source..

Comment: Well yes. The logic here is the http requests run regularly rather than every time they're called up, that way data can be returned immediately to anyone that makes a request to the flask server rather than needing to make a ton of http requests before responding.

Comment: Awesome James! I used simple_requests to get the asynchronous responses from the urls and it has done wonders to the performance of the code.